# How to change the image of my button on pointing my mouse over it?

Tags: android, touch

In the emulator on touching my button I want its image to be changed. I just want to bring my mouse pointer there, without click. This can be observed for thr keys of the emulator. On touch a blue image appears on the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html).

Check [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tinytutcustom_button_backgrounds-better_imagebutton-t4298.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no mouse in Android - hence there is no mouse-over, so the effect which you mentioned regarding the emulator keys is not applicable for Android applications

You could just react on **focused** and **pressed** events